# Using a reader to feed columns into a csv file

Tags: c#, csv, sqlconnection

I have a stored procedure that will return a column of 0 or more rows or account numbers.

If 0 rows I of course don't have to do anything but if 1 or more are returned I need to throw those account numbers into a csv file.

The data returned will look like this:

```
100000
200000
286598
```

Here is my method:

```
private static void ThirtyMinuteUpload(DateTime today)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("mySP", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connection.Open();
            if (command.ExecuteReader().HasRows)
            {
                // Create csv
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to throw those into a csv from my reader and name the file like this using the `today` variable passed in:

```
exlcusion_mmddyyhhmmss.csv
```

I have never worked with file creation and for now it can just be saved to my desktop.  Is something that is easy to do?

Comment: What type of output do you except? All in one row(Example A1:1000,B1:2000,C13000 etc...) Or all in one column(A1:1000,A2:2000,A3:3000 etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

**Update:** Fixed last comma problem.

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{
   if (dr.HasRows()) 
   {           
      string dateFormatted = today.ToString("MMddyyhhmmss");
      string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
      var writer = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}\exclusion_{1}.csv",
         path, dateFormatted);

      var cont = true;
      while (cont) 
      {
         // Grab the accountid before we read ahead
         var accId = dr["accountid"];

         // Read ahead to check if we've read the last record
         cont = dr.Read();

         // Last record, don't add comma
         if (!cont) 
         {
            writer.Write(accId); 
         }
         else 
         { 
            writer.Write(accId + ",");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using this `writer.WriteLine("{0},", reader["accountid"]);` Will it be a problem if it always adds a comma to the last record? `100000,200000,`

Comment: `continue` is a keyword in C#, you should probably use `@continue` instead.

Comment: I had to surround the while (cont) with a while (reader.Read()) or it would error out.  But with that addition it works perfectly thanks again.

Comment: I suggest at least in answers (but generally for all code IMO) that you don't use `var` when it is not clear which type it is. For instance we cannot immediately read without knowing which type `dr` will be in `var dr = command.ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: If there's only one column, why use any commas at all? There are none in the sample.

Comment: I assumed he was taking the account ids and making them into separate columns for his own reasons - I may have taken the title of the question too literally!

Comment: @DavidS. Sure you can. While the type name is not specific, this scenario is common enough to know it's a datareader.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That depends on who's reading the answer. This site is for inexperienced programmers too. Besides, making the type clear just removes the extra mental processing and makes it faster to read.

Comment: @DavidS. We'll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ThirtyMinuteUpload(DateTime today)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("mySP", cn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!rdr.HasRows) return;

            var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}exclusion_{2:MMddyyHHmmss}.csv",
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                Path.PathSeparator,
                today);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more abstract answer to your question. Rather than working with a `SqlDataReader`, I wrote a generic function that will write the data from any implementer of `System.Data.IDataReader` (`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` is just one class that does) to any `System.IO.Stream`, which includes files (using `FileStream`).

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the data from a given <see cref="IDataReader"/> <paramref name="reader"/> to the <paramref name="output"/> <see cref="Stream"/>.
/// There are optional parameters for writing a header, specifying the encoding, the buffer size, and whether or not the stream should be
/// closed when we're done reading.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="reader">Any object which implements <see cref="IDataReader"/>-- most likely a <see cref="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"/>.</param>
/// <param name="output">The stream to output the CSV contents to.</param>
/// <param name="writeHeader">When true, a header is written using the column names.</param>
/// <param name="encoding">Optional parameter (defaulting to UTF8 without BOM) denoting how the data should be encoded.</param>
/// <param name="bufferSize">Optional parameter (defaulting to 1KB) which is used as a buffer for writing the data.</param>
/// <param name="closeOutput">Optional parameter which, when true, closes the <paramref name="output"/> <see cref="Stream"/> after we're doing writing.</param>
private static void WriteCsv(IDataReader reader, Stream output, bool writeHeader = true, Encoding encoding = null, int bufferSize = 1024, bool closeOutput = false)
{
    // If no encoding is provided, use the same one the StreamWriter defaults to.
    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

    // Create a new writer to our CSV file.
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(output, encoding, bufferSize, !closeOutput))
    {
        // This will create an enumerable with every integer between 0 and FieldCount-1.
        // Allows us to do a concise for loop and use String.Join to handle the comma placement.
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount);

        // Keep looping as long as their are rows returned by the reader.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Write a header with the names of each column.
            if (writeHeader)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", indices.Select(i => reader.GetName(i) ?? ("column" + i))));
                writeHeader = false;
            }

            // Write the value of each field by its string representation separated by a comma.
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", indices.Select(i => (reader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : reader.GetString(i)) ?? "")));
        }
    }
}
```

This function gives you a great deal of control of some specifics like encoding and what kind of stream you're writing to (you could be writing to an HTTP response or a regular file, doesn't matter). If you get more complex data that you want to output into CSV files, I recommend reading [this article](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm) on CSV "standards."

This writer is naive-- it just writes the raw data it read from the `IDataReader`. If your content has a newline, carriage return, or a comma, it could confuse whatever will ultimately consume the output of your program. I would write a `CsvEncode` function that you feed each value into and it properly encodes it according to the rules listed in the article above.

This is just an example, not code you should actually use:

```
private static string CsvEncode(string value)
{
    // Handle commas within values.
    if (value.Contains(','))
    {
        // Strim so we get rid of beginning and trailing whitespaces we'd usually ignore.
        value = value.Trim();

        // If the value is already wrapped with quotation marks but has quotation marks within as well,
        if (value.StartsWith("\"") && value.EndsWith("\"") && value.IndexOf('\"', 1, value.Length-2) > 0)
            value = "\"" + value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2).Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
        else if (value.Contains("\"")) // Replace all quotations with two quotations, then wrap the final result.
            value = "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
    }
    return value;
}
```

And you would just update `WriteCsv` so when it's writing the values of the row, you invoke `CsvEncode`, something like (just an example):

```
// Write the value of each field by its string representation separated by a comma.
writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", indices.Select(i => CsvEncode(reader.IsDBNull(i) ? "" : reader.GetString(i) ?? ""))));
```

And just to be thorough, this is how you would call it:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (!reader.HasRows)
        return; // Nothing to do.

    // You want it on the desktop? We'll put it on the desktop.
    var filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}exclusion_{2:MMddyyHHmmss}.csv",
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        Path.PathSeparator,
        today);

    // Pass in the reader we got from executing the command. File.Create will replace any 
    // existing files. closeOutput is true because we do not keep a reference to the FileStream.
    WriteCsv(reader, File.Create(filePath), closeOutput: true);                
}
```